# Java EE inventory management lock Product quantity

Tags: jakarta-ee, inventory-management

We are trying to develop web e-commerce application using struts 1.2 on Jboss 4.2.+MySQL DB 5.1 which needs to be clustered. Need guidance before we start coding. We are stuck up. 

We have a Product table where we are entering the quantity , A Order table where we are storing the Customer order & Product details related to  add to cart functionality. There is a requirement which states that if a customer adds a Product to shopping cart with number of quantity, its should reduce from the Product table (the idea being to so that next customer can get the available quantity product). So how do we handle this in web e.g: A product total quantity is 15, Customer A comes & books for 12 , parallel Customer B comes & books for 6. How to lock & handle for the other scenario

1) So how do we lock product quantity this for each customer in web application (also clustered, synchronization may not work in clustered env as I think JVM would be different), Any other way?

2) what if the customer does not complete the shopping functionality, I mean we need to revert back the quantity from shopping cart to Product table?

Looking forward for your suggestion.

Comment: Do you have any design at all?  There are probably a few options you could do... perhaps use a message-based solution using JMS which manages the product locks.  Or managed it solely as part of the model backed by a database (where the managed entities can be across instances).  But it's a fairly large, open-ended question.

Comment: Thanks EdH for reply, No design yet , Just started with entities like table creation & normalization (table relation). But before starting coding want to take steps for the above scenario. Could you please help me in understanding using JMS for locking the quantity check.

Comment: There's nothing you can inherit.. it's all how you design your system.  I was thinking using JMS as an asynchronous approach to manage locking the domain objects of your system.  So, have a central entity which controls the locks for the (distributed) application.  Define your messages so the distributed app send messages for lock and object, and consumes messages which say whether they received the lock or whether they didn't.  I don't have anything specific in mind, but more an async approach rather than a synchronous service which might not support a distributed application architecture.

Comment: Thank you, please correct me am I able to understand you thought's. Lets assume a customer has clicked on add To cart . at the back end I need to create a Que which will send the data such as Product Id & Qty , I need to create a Listener for such Product as onMessage & check the Qty by using synchronized block ????

Comment: Yes.  The basics of JMS (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncgv.html) aren't going to do it for you.  It all comes down the the data that is sent along the queue and the logic executed as a result of the message.  But, if you want a distributed system, this is a way to handle this asynchronously across a cluster.  It's just that the way you write an application with asynchronous logic can be different from synchronous calls which might assume everything's in the same JVM.

Comment: Thank you EdH for the guidance, will create a base & share with you for more design approach